# afreechart - chart in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have been using afreechart to draw a few charts in my app, but I bumped into something I have not been able to work out by myself, so I hope someone here can give me a pointer in the right direction. I use the DemoView, which is included in the samples, and I pass the chart to the View. This has worked perfectly when my view was made up of a LinearLayout only, and the chart was added to this layout. However, if my view is a ScrollView, and to this ScrollView I add the same LinearLayout (built programmatically in exactly the same way), the chart does not show up. However, the rest of the layout looks the same. Any idea? Is there anything I should be setting in my chart in order for it to show up in a scrollview?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have sorted this issue with my charts in a ScrollView. It looks like I simply needed to set the layout parameters. In my case I used:

```
chartView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,500));
```

and now the chart shows up in the ScrollView.

Now I just have to find out why the line is not showing up in the legend of a XYlinechart, but that is a different story.

Comment: Thanks man you save me hours of digging I was using 
chartView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); But the chart still wasn't displaying. When I use 500 instead now it works perfectly